# Custom session ids

Tags: php, session

I am working on PHP. I want to set a custom session_id but the PHPSESSID does not change to my custom sessionid. Below i have a login handling file where custom id is set and a config_session file which is called at every page of the website. I have set the conif_session file in a way that session regenerates every 3 hours. When user is logged in, a custom sessionid will be regenerated appending user's id. When user is not logged in, a random sessionid will be regenerated.

1. Login

```
<?php   

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    try {
        require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
        require_once 'login_model.inc.php';
        require_once 'login_contr.inc.php';

        // ERROR HANDLERS
        $errors = [];

        if (is_input_empty($email, $pwd)) {
            $errors["empty_input"] = "빈 칸에 정보를 입력해주세요.";
        }

        $result = get_email($pdo, $email);

        if (is_email_wrong($result)) {
            $errors["login_incorrect"] = "이메일 또는 비밀번호가 틀렸습니다.";
        }
        if (!is_email_wrong($result) && is_pwd_wrong($pwd, $result["pwd"])) {
            $errors["login_incorrect"] = "이메일 또는 비밀번호가 틀렸습니다.";
        }

        require_once 'config_session.inc.php';

        if ($errors) {
            $_SESSION["errors_login"] = $errors;
   
            header("Location: ../login.php");
            die();
        }

        $newSessionId = session_create_id();
        $sessionId = $newSessionId . "_" . $result["id"];
        session_id($sessionId);

        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $result["id"];
        $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = htmlspecialchars($result["oauth_provider"]);
        $_SESSION["user_email"] = htmlspecialchars($result["email"]);
        $_SESSION["user_fullname"] = htmlspecialchars($result["fullname"]);

        $_SESSION["last_regeneration"] = time();

        header("Location:../index.php?login=success");
        $pdo = null;
        $stmt = null;

        die();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    die();
}
```

2. config_session

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 10800,
    'domain' => 'localhost',
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true
]);

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        
    if (!isset($_SESSION["last_regeneration"])) {
        regenerate_session_id_loggedin();
    } else {
        $interval = 60 * 180;
        if (time() - $_SESSION["last_regeneration"] >= $interval) {
            regenerate_session_id_loggedin();
        }
    }

} else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION["last_regeneration"])) {
        regenerate_session_id();
    } else {
        $interval = 60 * 180;
        if (time() - $_SESSION["last_regeneration"] >= $interval) {
            regenerate_session_id();
        }
    }
}

function regenerate_session_id_loggedin() 
{
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    $userId = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $newSessionId = session_create_id();    
    $sessionId = $newSessionId . "_" . $userId;
    session_id($sessionId);

    $_SESSION["last_regeneration"] = time();
}
function regenerate_session_id() 
{
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION["last_regeneration"] = time();
}
```

I tried debugging session_id($sessionId). Added error_log("Generated Session ID: " . $sessionId); under in the login file right under session_id($sessionId); and the custom session_id comes correctly.
I dont know why it is not set to PHPSESSID...

Comment: Try to use `session_start` **before everything else**

Comment: If you want to change PHPSESSID, you have to use session_name function, either way, the value of session_id will be shown correctly. It seems you're misunderstanding something !

Comment: Question: why do you think you _need_ a custom Session ID? How is it helping you?

Comment: @ADyson I am very new to PHP. I was creating a custom sessionid to make PHPSESSID more unique.

Comment: Is there any benefit from doing that?

Comment: `I am very new to PHP`...then this is probably not something you ought to dabble in yet. `I was creating a custom sessionid to make PHPSESSID more unique`...why? Again, how does that help you? In what way does it make your application better? Why do you care, or even need to know, what the session IDs look like? In 20 years of working with PHP I don't think I've even ever looked at one. It simply isn't an issue that anyone needs to think about, in 99.99% of cases.

Comment: @ADyson I guess there is really no point of setting a custom session id. I wanted to implement it regardless. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: So you seem to be saying now that you want spend a lot of time on, and for us to spend time helping you with, something which you know is pointless? Forgive me but I have other things I need to do. Good luck.

Comment: @ADyson I am learning PHP doing this ecommerce project. Why are you angry? You have clarified my doubts because you pointed out that there is no use of setting custom session id. You’ve helped me.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea I was angry. I merely said that I've got better things to do than assist with a meaningless task (just so that you know why I wasn't continuing to reply) - which is true. If you want to proceed with that task nonetheless - which was what I understood you to have said you were going to do - then  you are very welcome to do so. I would advise though that if you're only learning PHP, then - entirely regardless or otherwise of the usefulness of changing session IDs - this is not something to mess with until you've got much more experience.